# Bind a specific checkbox of a checkbox column in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, data-binding

I am in my very very first steps in wpf and I am trying to maintain some code. Try to be quite simplistic in your explanations , I will try to use as correct definitions as I can.

```
<TextBox Background="#ECECECEC" 
               Text="Bla bla"
               Visibility="{Binding ElementName=UseCwdCheckBox , Path=Context.SettingsHandler.UseCWDForTyping, Converter={StaticResource VisibleIfTrueConverter}}"   >
</TextBox>
```

For the moment, the textbox above is visible, if some checkbox is checked. But that is not the intended behavior. I want to bind a specific checkbox of the (below) DataGridCheckBoxColumn named "Enabled". However, I am not sure of its place in the column. I can be sure however, that the next column (in the same datagrid), which is called "names" will have a name = "John" i.e. So, all in one sentence: I want the textbox to become visible if John's checkbox is checked.

```
             <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="Enabled"
                                            Binding="{Binding Enabled, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                                            Width="60">
                        <DataGridCheckBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
                            <Style TargetType="CheckBox">
                                <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
                                <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center" />
                            </Style>
                        </DataGridCheckBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
                    </DataGridCheckBoxColumn>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use code behind to  the CheckBox in the first column of the Datagrid and TextBox .

```
  private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Binding binding = new Binding() { Source= (dataGrid1.Columns[0].GetCellContent(dataGrid1.Items[0]) as CheckBox) ,Path=new PropertyPath ("IsChecked")};
            binding.UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged;
            binding.Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay;
            binding.Converter = new VisibleIfTrueConverter();
            textBox1.SetBinding(TextBox.VisibilityProperty, binding);

        }
```